# Replace HTML for image in Mobile Design. Like Paypal.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright Noob alert! 
I am sorry in advance is question is already answered on here. If so please link me to the question because I couldn't find it.

I am building a responsive site right now and I have ran into two issues. 
The first one is when you are looking on any screen larger then a phone you see the name of my website in the top left corner. But I wanted to replace this with my logo once you are on a mobile device. One example of this is on Paypal.com. If you look on the desktop there is the Paypal logo and the words PayPal but on a mobile screen there is just the PayPal logo. 
What I have is written as follows:

```
<p id="logo"><a href="">Name</a></p>
```

How would I go about this? Would this be something I could do in CSS or HTML or is this more of a javascript/jQuery thing?

The second issue is similar. In the middle of the banner there is text that saids "don't have an account?". I wanted to display this text on a tablet and computer screen but hide it on a phone. This is written as follows:

Don't have an account?

How would you feel I should go about fixing this? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: You want Media Queries in css. Here's the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959848/how-to-implement-responsive-web-design-and-its-best-practices

Answer (score 1):

If you use media queries you can give your logo a different style on mobile.

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        #logo {
            display: hidden;
        }
}
```

This will hide the logo id when the screen size is below 767px. If you want something to only show on mobile, set the display to "block".