# My website is not being responsive and not resizing.

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, resize, responsiveness

I could really use some help, I have created my website http://hayleyryan.com/
and I can not get it to re-size to a smaller browser window or smaller device.

I have included `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` at the top of the document, I have also set everything to percentage widths. I have looked through all my CSS for anything that could be the cause- I can not find anything. 
It was working fine until I removed the meta tag and later put it back.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, by just adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` you cannot make a responsive webpage. It require a lot of other things.
Have a look at another question on stackoverflow which maybe helpful: [How to implement responsive web design and its best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959848/how-to-implement-responsive-web-design-and-its-best-practices)

Comment: Hi Raam,
Thanks for your answer! I apologise for using the wrong terminology- I understand I need to implement breakpoints to re-align the content. I realise 'responsive' is not the right word now- sorry! I am still quite new to a lot of these terms.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases

Lear this . [Responsive Web Design - Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
    /* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

    /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
    @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

    /* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
    @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }

@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) and (max-width: @screen-md-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Raam Singh is right, however for your specific case I would like to add, that your "curtains" ul is absolutely positioned.
You should either make it not absolute or add "width: 100%;".

Also your "desk" image should have "width: 100%;" if you want it to be resizable.

Comment: Thanks Laurynas, 
I think the position must be a style left over from I plugin I deleted earlier. Thank you! It fixed my problem. And thanks for the tip, I will fix the desk image too. :)

Answer (score 0):

please check the website before start the responsive

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Answer (score 0):

i tried all anwser but still my website is not responsive
i'll upload my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MNT CAB V2</title>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Final sticker MNT.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="Final sticker MNT.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="#ABOUT">About</a>g
        <a href="#SERVICES">Services</a>
        <a href="#GALLARY">Gallary</a>
        <a href="#CONTACT">Contact Us</a>
        <div class="animation start-home"></div>
      </nav>
```

this is my html its not responcive D:

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31788754)