# resizing html/css to fit different devices

Tags: html, css

I've created a website and when viewing it on an iPad or iPhone (example), it doesn't resize to fit the screen. It puts my text box (with name and social media buttons) to the left and my background image to the right (with whitespace in between these two elements). I'd like the site to work when viewed in portrait and landscape, as well as on desktop browsers (resizing with browser window)

How do I implement this into my code?

HTML:

```
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>My site!</title>
   <link href="background.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>

 <body>
   <section class="background">
    <div class="foreground">
     <div class="name-tag">MY SITE!
     </div>
      <ul class="social-media-list">
        <li class="social-media-link">
          <a href="https://twitter.com/" target=_blank"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/capsocial-round/500/twitter-128.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="social-media-link">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-icons-the-circle-set/48/youtube_circle-128.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="social-media-link">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/" target=_blank"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/linkedin_circle_color-512.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="social-media-link">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target=_blank"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-white-social-media/32/instagram_online_social_media-128.png"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
  </section>
 </body>

 </html>
```

CSS:

```
   /* Body Margin*/

body {
  margin: 0;
 }


 /*  Font family avenir-light*/

 @font-face {
   font-family: 'avenir-light';
  src: url('fonts/avenir-light.eot') format('eot'), url('fonts/avenir-light.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/avenir-light.ttf') format('ttf');
}


 /* Background Div*/

.background {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


 /* Background Div: after*/

.background:after {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   content: '';
   background-image: url("bkgd.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   -webkit-animation: fadein 3s;
   /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s;
    /* Firefox < 16 */
    -ms-animation: fadein 3s;
   /* Internet Explorer */
   -o-animation: fadein 3s;
   /* Opera < 12.1 */
   animation: fadein 3s;
   /*Fade In Animation*/
 }


 /* Fade in animations */

 @keyframes fadein {
   from {
     opacity: 0.2;
   }
   to {
     opacity: 1;
   }
}


 /* Firefox < 16 */

 @-moz-keyframes fadein {
   from {
    opacity: 0.2;
   }
   to {
     opacity: 1;
   }
 }


  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */

  @-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {
     opacity: 0.2;
       }
    to {
     opacity: 1;
   }
 }


 /* Internet Explorer */

 @-ms-keyframes fadein {
   from {
     opacity: 0.2;
   }
   to {
     opacity: 1;
   }
 }


 /* Opera < 12.1 */

 @-o-keyframes fadein {
   opacity: 0.2;
 }

 to {
   opacity: 1;
 }


 /* Foreground div */

 .foreground {
   margin-top: 20px;
   position: relative;
   width: 400px;
   height: 100px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #555;
     border-radius: 10px;
   /*Fade In Animation*/
   -webkit-animation: fadein 5s;
   /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 5s;
   /* Firefox < 16 */
   -ms-animation: fadein 5s;
   /* Internet Explorer */
   -o-animation: fadein 5s;
   /* Opera < 12.1 */
   animation: fadein 5s;
    z-index: 1;
   }


 /* Name Tag */

  .name-tag {
   font-family: 'avenir-light';
   text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
  }


 /* Social Media List*/

 .social-media-list {
   list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
     padding: 0;
    }


  /* Social Media Item*/

  .social-media-link img {
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
  }

 .social-media-link img:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
   /* Safari */
   transform: scale(1.2);
  /* Standard syntax */
 }
```

Comment: Follow this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959848/how-to-implement-responsive-web-design-and-its-best-practices

Comment: @SahilDhir I've had a look, nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap for this purpose. Bootstrap divides the screen into 12 columns. for different screen size different classes are there like for medium size you can use col-md-3 or for small size devices col-sm-3 and so on.

Comment: Just download bootstrap file and use it as external css. In that file there will be predefined classes, you have to use that only.