# Page does not apply @media in special mode

Tags: css

Hello I have a problem because when I use `'toggle device toolbar'` @media does not work, but when I narrow page manually, everything applies. I am using Ubuntu, google chrome.

```
css:

@media only screen and (max-width: 60rem) {
    .shop {
       grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        
    }

}
```

Comment: what is "toggle device toolbar"? which device and which toolbar exactly?
also, what is "special mode"?

Comment: When you get into a console in a google chrome browser, you have there a button 'toogle device toolbar' which allows you to change width and height as well as you can choose multiple devices. Smartphones, laptops and in this mode @media queries does not work, nevertheless when you narrow the page manually everything works and page is RWD.

Comment: Sounds like the normal way of rendering a small page, this is nothing special about it with this method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54284854/responsive-web-design-by-meta-tag did you put this in your head section?